# passing array as argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var srno=1;
        var srnoarray= new Array();
        $(".addRow").click(function(){

            var ToAppend='<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:40px;" name="srno_[]" id="id_srno_'+srno+'" value="'+srno+'" readonly="readonly"  /></td>';

            ToAppend+='<td>';
            ToAppend+='<select class="form-control" name="product_name_'+srno+'" id="product_name_'+srno+'" onchange="return onSelectChangeajax(this.value,'+srno+')">';
            ToAppend+='<option value="0">Select Product</option>';
            ToAppend+='</select>';
            ToAppend+='</td>';

            ToAppend+='<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_prise_'+srno+'" id="product_prise_'+srno+'" placeholder="Purchase Prise" onblur="calAmount('+srno+')" /></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_qty_'+srno+'" id="product_qty_'+srno+'" value="1" placeholder="Quantity" onblur="calAmount('+srno+')"/></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_amt_'+srno+'" id="product_amt_'+srno+'" placeholder="Amount" onblur="calAmount('+srno+')"/></td><td><img src="dist/img/removerow.png" onclick="deleteRow(this),deleteArrayVal.apply(this,'+srnoarray+');" /></td></tr>';
            srnoarray.push(srno);
            $("#purchaseItems").append(ToAppend);

            console.log(srnoarray);
            srno++;
        });

});

function deleteRow(rwo)
{   
    var i=rwo.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("purchaseItems").deleteRow(i);
}
function deleteArrayVal(val)
{
    console.log(val);

}
```

Above functions add the dynamic row and remove the row in table. I have created an array  called srnoarray and I have added srno in that array on every tr get added dynamically. deleteRow is the function to remove tr, **but when i remove tr i want to remove particular srno from srnoarray.**

```
<img src="dist/img/removerow.png" onclick="deleteRow(this),deleteArrayVal('+srnoarray+');" />
```

I tried passing array as argument in the function but that is not of use.
how should I do that??

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to use the method here :
document.getElementById("purchaseItems").deleteRow(i);

For this, you might need to add the deleteRow as a prototype to work.

But please elaborate a little bit what exactly you want to delete from the array.

Thanks.

Comment: see, when i add row , I add srno in array that is 1,2,3... etc on console I get [1,2,3] this. this is when i add row, what i needed is, suppose i clicked on remove on 2nd tr that is 2nd srno. the table row gets removed, but i also want to remove this 2 from array. thats why i tried to pass array as function parameter and pop in that function but it is not possible.

Comment: You can use : var idx = srnoarray.indexOf(i); and then srnoarray.splice(idx, 1); Please let me know if it worked. i Is the element that you want to be removed from the array.

Comment: var idx = srnoarray.indexOf(i); to use this i have to pass srnoarray to function then only i can use this way. problem is i am not able to pass this array as function parameter.

Comment: In this case pass the array as string and encode it as a function parameter. Eg : deleteArrayVal(JSON.stringify(srnoarray)); And in the method var arr = JSON.parse(srnoarray); where srnoarray it's also the parameter. If you use val then JSON.parse(val);

Comment: but is this is going to affect that original array globally??

Comment: it should affect it , of course. another qorkaround is to make the click event separately from <img tag. Add a function and say document.getElementsByTagName('img').onclick = function(event) { // do your stuff here }; Check html dom method : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp and from there you wil be able to pass the array as an argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79947/discussion-between-soham-s-more-and-mihai-enescu).

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteArrayVal(value) {
    var index = arr.indexOf(value);
    if (index > -1) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: arr is the array if you are passing to the function, it is not working

Comment: @Soham s More you dont need to pass the array just pass the value, and define array in global scope

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend to use a templating engine (e.g. [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/))
to keep your js cleaner (no HTML in jquery). Improves readability.

I also would look at angularjs because then you will have it easier to keep your js data in synch with your DOM.

For your row remove button you could add a data attribute to each row so you can easily get the clicked row in your click handler.

Please have a look at the demo below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jukmqb40/1/).

```js
var row   = $("#row-template").html(), 
    rowTemplate = Handlebars.compile(row),
    purchasedItems = [];

/*
var context = {srno: 0};
var html    = rowTemplate(context);
*/
function addRow() {
    purchasedItems.push({
        srno: purchasedItems.length+1,
        products: [ {// just some dummy products
            name:'pizza',
            selected: 'selected'
        },
        {name:'pasta'
        },
        {name:'hamburger'}
        ]
    });
    
    console.log(purchasedItems);
    refreshTable();
}

function refreshTable() {
    $('#purchaseItems').empty();
    $.each(purchasedItems, function(index, item) {
        $('#purchaseItems').append(rowTemplate(item));
    });
}

function getRowId(context) {
    return $(context).parent().parent().attr('data-rowId');
}

/* not working --> needed to update the data in the array
$('#purchaseItems').on('change', '.productSelection', function() {
    var index = getRowId(this);
    console.log(index);
    
});
*/

$('#purchaseItems').on('click', '.removeRow', function() {
    var index = getRowId(this);
    console.log(index);
    purchasedItems.pop(index);
    console.log(purchasedItems);
    refreshTable();
});

$('#add').click(function() {
    addRow();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <tr data-rowId="{{srno}}">
      <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:40px;" name="srno_[]" id="id_srno_{{srno}}" value="{{srno}}" readonly="readonly"  /></td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="product_name_{{srno}}" id="product_name_{{srno}}" class="productSelection">
            {{#each products}}
            <option value="{{this.name}}" {{this.selected}}>{{this.name}}</option>
            {{/each}}
            
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_prise_{{srno}}" id="product_prise_{{srno}}" placeholder="Purchase Prise" onblur="calAmount({{srno}})" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_qty_{{srno}}" id="product_qty_{{srno}}" value="1" placeholder="Quantity" onblur="calAmount({{srno}})"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_amt_{{srno}}" id="product_amt_{{srno}}" placeholder="Amount" onblur="calAmount({{srno}})"/>
    </td>
      <td>
          <!--<img src="dist/img/removerow.png"--> <button class="removeRow">remove</button>
      </td>
   </tr>   
</script>

<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="purchaseItems"></div>
```